# Understanding error in bayesian inference

Tags: probability, bayesian, inference, conditional-probability, error

Let us say we have:

1. Data $X$
2. Parameter that we are trying to estimate is $\Theta$

The Bayesian estimation method is to

1. Assume a prior on $\Theta$
2. Sample $x$ from $X$
3. Use Bayes theorem. Compute the posterior $\Theta\mid(X=x)$

Now, in case a point estimate is to be reported then one way is to report lowest mean square estimate $\hat{\Theta} = E[\Theta \mid X]$. This is supposed to be the parameter that has lowest mean squared error.

The error being defined as $\bar{\Theta}=\hat{\Theta} - \Theta$.

Now, two supposedly intuitive properties of $\bar{\Theta}$ are

1. $E[\bar{\Theta}] = 0$
2. $E[\bar{\Theta} \mid X] = 0$

Whenever I think of expected values I think there is an inherent distribution that the expectation is computed using. What is the distribution over which $E[\bar{\Theta}] = 0$ is computed? There are two sources of randomness namely $X$ and $\Theta$.

Moreover, Expectations should be able to be estimated by iterated sampling. That procedure, I think, would like the following in the case of $E[\bar{\Theta} \mid X]$

1. Sample $x$ from $X$.
2. Compute posterior $\Theta \mid (X = x)$
3. Compute $\hat{\theta} = E[\Theta \mid X = x]$. The expectation of the posterior computed above
4. Sample $\theta$ from posterior $\Theta \mid (X = x)$
5. Compute $\bar{\theta}=\hat{\theta} - \theta$

If you iterate over these 5 steps large number of times then the average of $\bar{\theta}$ would converge to 0

What would that procedure look like for $E[\bar{\Theta}]$? My attempt:

1. Sample $x$ from $X$
2. Sample $\theta$ from Prior $\Theta$
3. Compute posterior $\Theta \mid (X = x)$
4. Compute $\hat{\theta} = E[\Theta \mid X = x]$. The expectation of the posterior computed above
5. Compute $\bar{\theta}=\hat{\theta} - \theta$

If you iterate over these 5 steps large number of times then the average of $\bar{\theta}$ would converge to 0

Am I right?

Comment: This confuses me: "Now, in case a point estimate is to be reported then one way is to report lowest mean square estimate $\hat{\Theta} = E[\Theta \mid X]$. This is supposed to be the parameter that has lowest mean squared error."
To what degree is that a statement and to what degree a question? You seem to say that you want to report the *posterior mean* and make it the subject of the analysis thereafter. Or do you rather want a $X$-MSE minimizer? Or a $\Theta$-MSE minimizer? These three are not always the same.

Comment: The $X$-MSE minimizer is *sometimes* the same as the maximum likelihood estimator $\hat{\Theta}_\mathrm{ML}$ and the posterior *mode* is the maximum a posteriori estimator $\hat{\Theta}_\mathrm{MAP}$.

Comment: MAP makes sense for discrete distributions imo. You want to minimize the probability of being wrong. I don't want to maximize the likelihood of data. That is not Bayesian. I am looking for an estimator that minimises the expected error over $\Theta$

Comment: so when writing MSE, you had $(E[(\hat{Θ}−Θ)^\intercal(\hat{Θ}−Θ)|X]$
in mind? The not so nice things about this are: 1. some dimensions in Θ can be more or less meaningless than others, Distance in parameter space is therefore meaningless. 2. your computations so far only work for the posterior mean. I suggest that we forget about all things MSE, and that you indicate this up in your post.